# Confusion around base and derived class

Tags: c#

Basic scenario is this:

```
class MyBase {}
class MyClassA : MyBase {}
class MyClassB : MyBase {}
class MyClassC : MyBase {}
```

I have an `IEnumerable` collection of `MyBase` called `source` that actually contains a collection of either `MyClassA`, `MyClassB` or `MyClassC` items. Always only of one or the other.

I now want to create a filtered copy of that collection so I perform something similar to this:

```
IEnumerable<MyBase> filtered = source.Where(s => s.SomeProperty == someVar)
```

The problem is that if I call the GetType() method on source it says it's a collection of MyClass (A, B or C). However performing GetType() on filtered says that it's a collection of MyBase!

I need it to stay the same!

This is causing me problems as I am  binding the filtered collection to a `PivotControl` which now can't see the properties of `MyClass` that it needs in the filtered collection.

Because we don't know which of the classes A, B or C is in the collection, I have even tried this:

```
var entity = source.FirstOrDefault();    
IEnumerable<MyBase> filtered = FilterData(entity);

IEnumerable<MyBase> FilterData<T>(T typeOfObject) where T : MyBase
{
    IEnumerable<T> data = from s in source where s.SomeProperty == someVar select s as T;
    return data;
```

--OR--

```
    return source.Where(s => s.SomeProperty == someVar).Cast<T>()'
}
```

But still it shows in the same way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try enumerating it - like ToList or ToArray. It's really not clear what you want - put up some pics.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm really confused about your question, but think it's all about `Cast` extension method:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> filtered = source.Where(s => s.SomeProperty = someVar).Cast<MyClass>();
```

Comment: I've just edited the question to add a bit more info. Because the collection can be of any of the derived classes I don't know the actual type until it's in the FilterData method and surly that's doing that anyway, albeit slightly differently?